# Decision Trees Clasification Splitting Criteria in Algorithms, Metrics, and Category Types

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am trying to understand the decision tree. So I decided to construct a taxonomy to summarize it.

[image]

So to start, there are univariate and multivariate splitting criteria. In this case, focusing on decision tree univariate classification splitting criteria.

There is many, but I am not sure how to organize them in a hierarchal manner to see who descended from what. Any help is appreciated.

A fundamental question to be asked

Are all splitting criteria in the classification of decision tree **impurity based**?

Comment: Read [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/04/complete-tutorial-tree-based-modeling-scratch-in-python/#three). The author presents a few ways to split the decision. You might want to farther investigate once you get the general idea

Comment: @EranMoshe your answer is correct, please post it so I can select it , thank you